# Scrapy Import Error: No Module named Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, scrapy, package

I installed scrapy using the command line

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy@master --no-dependencies --upgrade
```

once installed, I tried importing scrapy in one of my python projects but an error arises saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Linkedin\script.py", line 7, in <module>
from scrapy import Selector
ImportError: No module named scrapy
[Finished in 0.983s]
```

What shall I do? Can't find a correct solution on Google yet!

Comment: 1. Did the pip install confirm that it is installed? 2. Did you check whether Python is in your PATH?

Comment: @FatihAkici, Yes I did. Initially, scrapy was not installing through the command line. So later I installed it on Visual code console and later I checked via the command line, it confirmed that it is already installed.

Comment: How are you running the script that raises the error?

Comment: I am running it on Atom. Initially on my script, for this syntax `sel =Selector(text=driver.page_source)`. I was getting an error (` 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'`).                                                                                     
So over searching on google, I came across Scrapy, where that uniode error could be solved by parsing the html                                                            
(`from scrapy.selector import Selector
  with open(person_path) as fp:
    sel = Selector(text=fp.read())

Comment: Why are you installing it from the Github source? Are you using virtual environments?

Comment: @AMC  No, initially I installed it from the Visual code console using "pip3 install scrapy" and it perfectly did but later I came to know that scrapy does not support Python 3.7 so later I installed via the Github on pipenv which had a compatibility of Py>=3.5 but still gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that everything is setup properly, your script is using the correct environment, etc.?

Comment: As far as I run the script and apart from that error, everything is working all fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use:

```
pip install Scrapy
```

[source](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html)

```
import scrapy

print(scrapy.__version__)
```

output:

```
1.8.0
```

when I run:

```
from scrapy import Selector
```

I get no error

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work. I guess there was some error in importing it. I installed it again on Visual code console since there was some error on the command line and its working fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it with conda and secondly set your python environ path.

Comment: I think this should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

#To install Scrapy using conda run:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
```

#if you’re already familiar with installation of Python packages, you can install Scrapy

```
pip install Scrapy
```